# How do I unit test if http request has been canceled using HttpTestingClientModule?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, httptestingcontroller

My component is invoking the method to get data from the server, it happens in `ngOnInit` lifecycle of the component. The request takes some time, and the user can navigate away from current view and destroy the component. In such a case, the get data request should be canceled. And this is what happens in actual application.

[Image of cancelled request in network tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BeXlX.png)

Now my goal is to unit test this behavior. What approach should I take? My current implementation is pretty naive and doesn't work...

What should I do in order to simulate request cancellation?

Here's my approach:

Component class:

```
@Component({
    ...
    providers: [ProjectsOverviewService] <-- Lifecycle of service depends on component
    ...
})
export class ProjectsOverviewComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(private projectsOverviewService: ProjectsOverviewService) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.projectsOverviewService.getSomeData();
    }
}
```

Service class:

```
@Injectable()
export class ProjectsOverviewService implements OnDestroy {
    private someData: Data;
    private serviceDestroyed$ = new Subject();

    constructor(private projectPageService: ProjectPageService) {}

    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.serviceDestroyed$.next();
    }

    getSomeData() {
        this.projectPageService.projectsGetAll$
        .pipe(takeUntil(this.serviceDestroyed$))
        .subscribe(data => this.someData = data);
    }
}
```

Spec file:

```
let component: ProjectsOverviewComponent;
let fixture: ComponentFixture<ProjectsOverviewComponent>;
let httpTestingController: HttpTestingController;

beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        imports: [
            HttpClientTestingModule
        ],
        declarations: [ProjectsOverviewComponent],
        providers: [ProjectsServiceProxy]
    }).compileComponents();
});

beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ProjectsOverviewComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    httpTestingController = TestBed.inject(HttpTestingController);
    fixture.detectChanges();
});

it('should cancel get some data request when component is destroyed', () => {
    const req = httpTestingController.expectOne('/api/services/app/Projects/GetAll');

    console.log(req); // TestRequest

    component.ngOnDestroy();

    expect(req.cancelled).toBe(true); // Fails - expected false, to be true.
});
```

Comment: Have you tried calling `httpTestingController.verfiy()` to check that there are no outstanding requests?

Comment: I just tried it right now. I have added it before the assertion, and it is not throwing any errors.